# programming a gpu without using any library like cuda or opencl?

Tags: c, cuda, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I want to know is there a way that we can use GPU for computing (for example multiplication of two matrix ) without using any library or API . I just want to write a program in C and I don't want to use CUDA or OpenCL or anything like that.

Comment: Do you want to develop hardware that communicate with your GPU via PCI or something to avoid even help of PC BIOS?

Comment: Or allow the BIOS or UEFI to just load and launch your code, then access I/O port or something directly?

Comment: @MikeCAT OpenCL and/or CUDA aren't hardware - it's just an easy, comprehensive and standardized interface to GPGPU. Sorry for talking in place of TS, but seems like he just wanted to ask how to interconnect with GPGPU directly, without any existing interfaces on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The really short answer, is no, you can't do that. All of the standard "C or C++ like" GPU programming models I am familiar with require you to use an API (compute APIs like OpenCL or OpenCL, or graphics APIs like OpenGL and Direct3D) to manage the device and load and execute a shader or compute kernel in parallel on the target GPU.

About the closest (probably only) thing which abrogates the need to use the underlying hardware APIs is compiled assisted parallelism for GPUs, like [OpenACC](http://www.openacc.org/). There, you can use pre-processor directives to decorate C, C++, or Fortran code and rely on the compiler to generate parallel code for the device. The underlying compute or graphics APIs and drivers are still there and still used, but you don't see them.

Comment: I want to do programming directly to gpu. for example add 2 numbers. since cuda and opencl change their code to assembly there should be a way. Do you know about assembly coding on gpu and accessing gpu directly ?

Comment: assembly coding - yes: https://github.com/NervanaSystems/maxas

but direct access means that you will reimplement part of the video driver. does you really want it?

if you does need the library that can be used from any C compiler - look at OpenCL

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to compile C directly to a gpu. However, you could write your own shader and use that to do your calculations. Have a look at HLSL and GLSL.

Comment: Wouldn't using a shader language via Direct3D or OpenGL count as "using a library or API"?

Comment: @talonmies Well, yes. Hence "There is no way to compile C directly to a gpu" ;)